# drawing to canvas fails on first load. Refresh and it works

Tags: javascript, canvas

Here is my function.

```
drawButtons: function() {
    gameController.ctx.strokeStyle='pink';
    gameController.ctx.fillStyle='rgba(128,128,128,1)';
    gameController.ctx.lineWidth=2;
    this.roundedRect(gameController.ctx,105,162,160,50,10,true,true);
    this.roundedRect(gameController.ctx,105,240,160,50,10,true,true);

    gameController.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(153,051,000,1)';
    gameController.ctx.font = "35px AR DARLING";
    gameController.ctx.fillText("1 Player",120,200);
    gameController.ctx.fillText("2 Player",120,278);
    }
```

None of it gets drawn on first load of the webpage. I can add code to show where i call the method if anyone wishes to see that. Maybe i have to add .onload(), but i only know how to do that when adding an Image to the canvas, not fillText etc. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide code which is functionnal and **complete**. `this.roundedRect is undefined`.

Comment: I could do that, but the problem surely isn't with roundedRect(), because the fillText is unrelated, and also doesn't load on the first attempt. Should i add where i call the method?

Comment: Give us something that works (well, not the problematic part). Preferrably something like a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com) or a [JSBin](http://www.jsbin.com). This way we'll solve your problem quickly.

Comment: I managed to use window.onload within my drawButtons method and it solved the problem. Thanks. 

 drawButtons: function() {
 window.onload = (function(){

Answer (score 0):

window.onload within my drawButtons method is the solution.

```
drawButtons: function() {
    window.onload = (function(){
    gameController.ctx.strokeStyle='pink';
    gameController.ctx.fillStyle='rgba(128,128,128,1)';
    gameController.ctx.lineWidth=2;
    nonGameContent.roundedRect(gameController.ctx,105,162,160,50,10,true,true);
    nonGameContent.roundedRect(gameController.ctx,105,240,160,50,10,true,true);

    gameController.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(153,051,000,1)';
    gameController.ctx.font = "35px AR DARLING";
    gameController.ctx.fillText("1 Player",120,200);
    gameController.ctx.fillText("2 Player",120,278);
    })},
```